# How to add a service which executable file has a space and requires parameters?

Tags: windows, windows-service

I would like a python script as a Windows service, using `sc`. The problem is that the path to the executable has a space and requires parameters.

Therefore

```
sc create DNSResolver127 binPath= '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe" D:/32dsdnsproxy/32dsdnsproxy.py'
```

fails (I tried to enclose the whole option in single quotes)

How to add such a service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the quote marks like this:

```
sc create MyService binpath= "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\python.exe\" D:/32dsdnsproxy/32dsdnsproxy.py"
```

... but keep in mind that this will only work if `32dsdnsproxy.py` is designed to run as a service, otherwise you'll need to use a tool such as [nssm](https://nssm.cc/) or Apache Daemon's [procrun](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html) to launch your application as a service.

Comment: Thank you. Is there something special to handle when starting a script as a service?(sorry, I am from the Unix world)

Comment: `nssm` is a godsend. I installed the script without any problems. Thank you!

Comment: Windows services have to interact with the operating system, at a minimum they need to report that they have successfully started.  I've never tried this myself, but I believe that you *can* write a windows service in Python, e.g., see [here](https://www.thepythoncorner.com/2018/08/how-to-create-a-windows-service-in-python/) - I expect that nssm will meet your immediate needs, but knowing that this is possible might come in handy later. :-)

Comment: Using Windows 11 the arguments do not show up in services info

Comment: @jjxtra, odd, they do on my Windows 11 box.  For example, the Cryptographic Services service shows the path to executable as  `C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k NetworkService -p`